# How to calculate max-height with using max-length property in Textarea

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[image]

in the above example,input has max character length so user can not able to write anymore. So I have to don't allow resizing beyond 200 characters since that is max for this field. So i think need to calculate max-height property.

Pass maxLength property is 200 , line-height is 18px. Is there any way to calculate max height with these values ?

[i found an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471371/set-max-characters-in-textarea-base-on-textarea-height-and-width) but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: TL:DR; Nope... The needed size of the textarea will depend on a number of factors such as the font being used, the size of the font. What about new lines add a few and you'll need more height. It would also depend upon the mix of characters used e.g. capital x's `X` and m' `M` take up much more space than periods '.' and i's `i` (assuming a variable width font)

Comment: @phuzi  what is the best way for my scenario ? how can achieve that i want ?

Comment: I'd take a look at [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-contenteditable) and [Making content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) on MDN. Style it like a textarea and you have a dynamically sized textarea

Answer (score 0):

You should probably think about `contenteditable`. Add a few event listeners and you've got a dyanmically sized text area.

- [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-contenteditable) on MDN
- [Making content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) also on MDN

To do what you want has too many variables to be done "properly" and the needed size of the textarea will depend on a number of factors such as the font being used, the size of the font.

Of course the content itself would also affect the required size, add a few new lines and you'll need even more height.

The mix of characters would also affect the needed size i.e. capital x's `X` and m's `M` take up much more space than periods '.' `.` and i's `i` (assuming a variable width font.)

```css
.editable {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="editable">
  This text can be edited by the user.
</div>
```

Comment: in my example there is need to be resize icon and user should be able to resize texarea until maxlength filled. Contenteditable good solution to make dynamic size but i think this not solve my problem

Comment: I'm sure a little bit of JS would allow resizing.