# How to show jquery error message on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a `textarea` that word count is limited to a maximum of 500. I want to check the word count value greater than 500 then show an error message below of that textarea

Now I got the correct word count but how to show the error message and stop to entering values.

**html**

```
<div class="">
   <div class="form-control-wrapper">
     <textarea name="project_desc" id="project_desc" class="form-control project_desc"  rows="6"><?php if(isset($project_desc)){ echo $project_desc; }?></textarea>
   </div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#project_desc').keyup(function(e){

var value = $('#project_desc').val();
var length = value.trim().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").split(" ").length;
if(length >= 500)
  {
    //show an error message ans stop entering values
  }
 });
```

Comment: its quite simple add a class error like this , $("#project_desc").addClass("error");
var str=$("#project_desc").val();
$("#project_desc").val(str.substr(0, 500) + '..');

Comment: @YamenNassif https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854288/val-vs-text-for-textarea

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for pointing it out will update

Comment: Why didn't you use `maxlength` property ? `<textarea maxlength="500"></textarea>` holds only 500 char.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna because he wants the max **word count** to be 500, not the number of characters. But I see that almost everyone who has answered so far has missed that part :)

Comment: @vi5ion Same thing happens to me. My bad. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this (note I set max 10 words for testing)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.project_desc').on("input", function(e) {
    var value = this.value;
    var maxWords = $(this).attr("data-maxwords");
    var wordString = $.trim(value.replace(/[\s]+/g, " "));
    var numWords = wordString.length==0?0:wordString.split(" ").length;
    var tooLong = numWords > maxWords;
    
    if (tooLong) {
      var trimmed = value.split(/\s+/, maxWords).join(" ");
      // Add a space at the end to keep new typing making new words
      $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
      numWords = maxWords;
    }
    $(this).next(".project_desc_message").html("<br/>"+numWords+"/"+maxWords+" words")
  }).trigger("input");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <div class="form-control-wrapper">
    <textarea name="project_desc" data-maxwords="10" id="project_desc1" class="form-control project_desc" rows="6">this field has too many words in it from the server</textarea><span class="project_desc_message"></span>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="form-control-wrapper">
    <textarea name="project_desc" data-maxwords="20" id="project_desc2" class="form-control project_desc" rows="6"></textarea><span class="project_desc_message"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the older version from before I found the duplicate.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.project_desc').on("input", function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var length = $.trim(value).replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").split(" ").length;
    var maxLength = $(this).attr("data-maxwords");
    var tooLong = length >= maxLength;
    $(this).next(".project_desc_error").html("<br/>Please enter max "+maxLength+" words").toggle(tooLong);
    if (tooLong) {
      this.value = $.trim(value).replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").split(" ").slice(0, maxLength).join(" ");
    }
  }).trigger("input");
});
```

```css
.project_desc_error {
  display: none; color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <div class="form-control-wrapper">
    <textarea name="project_desc" data-maxwords="10" id="project_desc1" class="form-control project_desc" rows="6">this field has too many words in it from the server</textarea><span class="project_desc_error"></span>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <div class="form-control-wrapper">
    <textarea name="project_desc" data-maxwords="20" id="project_desc2" class="form-control project_desc" rows="6"></textarea><span class="project_desc_error"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: okey..but stop further entering..here we can enter values after the limit reached

Comment: The test should block more words - I had to run so perhaps I missed something

Comment: its working well.can i generalize this.i have 5 textareas with different word count limit

Comment: Please see update for a generalised version with too much data from server too

Comment: Another update for a more elegant version

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#project_desc').val(value.slice(0,-1))` to remove the last type character when inside your error state.

This `$(this).after('<div class="error">this is your error.</div>')` will add an error message after your `textarea`

Please note that I reduced the `word count` in the example below.

```js
$('#project_desc').keyup(function(e) {

  var value = $('#project_desc').val();
  var length = value.trim().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").split(" ").length;
  if (length >= 3) {
    $('#project_desc').val(value.slice(0, -1))
    if ($(".error").length == 0) {
      $(this).after('<div class="error">this is your error.</div>')
    }
  } else {
    $(".error").remove()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <div class="form-control-wrapper">
    <textarea name="project_desc" id="project_desc" class="form-control project_desc" rows="6"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```js
$('#project_desc').keyup(function(e){
     var max=5;
     if (e.which < 0x20) {
        // e.which < 0x20, then it's not a printable character
        // e.which === 0 - Not a character
        return;     // Do nothing
    }
    if (this.value.length == max) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (this.value.length > max) {
        // Maximum exceeded
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, max);
    }

var value = $('#project_desc').val();
var length = value.trim().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").length;



if(length >= 500)
  {
    $("#error").show();
  }
  else{
    $("#error").hide();
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
   <div class="form-control-wrapper">
     <textarea name="project_desc" id="project_desc" class="form-control project_desc"  rows="6"></textarea>
     <span style="color:red;display:none" id="error">
      Limit Exceeded
     </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its okey.but i need to prevent entering values

Comment: Check now. Please

Comment: Set max variable to 500.

Comment: For more details, refer to this to prevent length http://jsfiddle.net/3uhNP/1/

Comment: 500 words. Not 500 chars

Comment: Refer to this please. http://jsfiddle.net/7DT5z/9/

Comment: Why not post that code then It is much more elegant - assuming it is your code

Comment: If solution already exist in web I think so then it is not necessary to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a **real-time counter** that would show the number of characters. And on submit of this form, you can check the value of `count`, if its less than 0, do not allow the form to submit.

```js
maxWords = 500;

$('#count').text(maxWords);

$('#project_desc').bind('keyup keydown', function() {
  var count = $('#count');
  var valueEntered = $(this).val()
  var characters = valueEntered.trim().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").split(" ").length;

  if (characters > maxWords) {
    count.addClass('over');
  } else {
    count.removeClass('over');
  }

  count.text(maxWords - characters);
});
```

```css
#projecterror {
  display: none
}

.over {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <div class="form-control-wrapper">
    <textarea name="project_desc" id="project_desc" class="form-control project_desc" rows="6"></textarea>
  </div><span id="projecterror">Please enter only 500 words</span>
</div>
<p>
  <strong>You have <em id="count"></em> characters remaining</strong>
</p>
```

Comment: Will change the variable name.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("#txtPostBody").on("input", function () {
            $("#PostBodyCount").text('Count : ' + this.value.length);

            if (this.value.length > 158) {
                $("#txtPostBody").css('border-color', 'red');
            }
            else {
                $("#txtPostBody").css('border-color', '');
            }
        });
```

Use this one.

Comment: 500 words. Not 500 chars

Answer (score -1):

remove split(" ") :

```
$('#project_desc').keyup(function(e){
var value = $('#project_desc').val();
var length = value.trim().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").length;
if(length >=500)
 {
   //show an error message ans stop entering values
 }
});
```

Comment: i tested it and work

Comment: Where is the error message?

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work for you. Reference taken from [How to prevent user to enter text in textarea after reaching max character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414420/how-to-prevent-user-to-enter-text-in-textarea-after-reaching-max-character-limit)

Try this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var max = 10;
    $('textarea#project_desc').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which < 0x20) {
            return;     // Do nothing
        }
        myval = $(this).val().trim().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").split(" ").length;
        if (myval >= max) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.limittext').show();
        } else if (myval > max) {
            this.value = myval.substring(0, max);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
   <div class="form-control-wrapper">
     <textarea name="project_desc" id="project_desc" class="form-control project_desc"  rows="6"></textarea><span class="limittext" style="display:none;">Limit reached</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 500 words. Not 500 chars - you count words but limit on chars

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
 $('#project_desc').keyup(function(e){

  var value = $(this).val(); // if it is not worked than try
  var value = $(this).text(); //if not work upper condition
  var length = value.trim().replace(/[\s]+/g, " ").split(" ").length;
  if(length >= 500)
  {
    alert('You cant write anymore');
    e.preventDefault();

  }
 });
```

Comment: my question is how to show an error message in that particular condition

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: can you try this?